# Преобразовать тип данных в запросе select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли не меняя тип данных в таблице, вывести через select столбец с иным типом данных? К примеру, в столбце varchar, а я хочу int (в столбце нет других символов кроме 0-9).

Comment: select CAST(СтолбецСтрока AS INT) as НовоеИмяСтолбца from table

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(ColumnName AS INT) AS ColumnName
FROM TableName
```

Comment: `TRY_CAST()` всё же безопаснее... мало ли что там и кто говорит про значения в поле. Сто пудов у автора нет в таблице констрейнта, который обеспечивает соответствие значения описанному шаблону.

Comment: Благодарю, try_cast тоже опробую

Comment: @Akina try_cast - это уже спицифика определённой базы двнных, а CAST - это спецификация SQL

Comment: @Виктор Это да. Но вроде как вопрос явно помечен тегом SQL Server..

Comment: Да, microsoft sql server